# ionic image saving and retrieving and display

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

I created the application using ionic angularJS ,I did to open the camera and capture the image using below snippet.

//Open Camera

> Plugin : cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera

```
$scope.takePhoto = function () {
var options = {
quality: 75,
destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
allowEdit: true,
encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
targetWidth: 300,
targetHeight: 300,
popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
saveToPhotoAlbum: false
};

$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {

$scope.urlImg = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;


}, function (err) {
//An error occured. Show a message to the user

alert('Camera not avilable');

});
}
```

And now I need to save the image into a Gallery(Photos Album) and I need to save the image name into SQLite Db.

And now How can I call the image and display it in a  tag using the name which I have saved in SQLite Db.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below snippets to done the activity and suggest me, If anything wrong.

> Take Photo

```
$scope.takePhoto = function () {

//2
var options = {
destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, // Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
allowEdit : false,
encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
};

//3
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {

//4
onImageSuccess(imageData);

function onImageSuccess(fileURI) {
createFileEntry(fileURI);
}

function createFileEntry(fileURI) {
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileURI, copyFile, fail);
}

//5
function copyFile(fileEntry) {
var name = fileEntry.fullPath.substr(fileEntry.fullPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
alert(name);
alert(fileEntry.fullPath);
var newName = makeid() + name;
alert(newName);

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function(fileSystem2) {
fileEntry.copyTo(
fileSystem2,
newName,
onCopySuccess,
fail
);
},
fail);
}

//6
function onCopySuccess(entry) {
$scope.$apply(function () {

alert(entry.nativeURL);

**// Display your captured image in the <img> tag**

$scope.urlImg = entry.nativeURL;

 **// you can able to save the above path into SQLite and display it back when you required – suggest me if the approach is wrong**


});
}

function fail(error) {
console.log("fail: " + error.code);
}

function makeid() {
var text = "";
var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

for (var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
}
return text;
}

}, function(err) {
console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Hello , your code works prefectly , but how can I show the image and make sure it doesn't disappear after I close and open the app again .

Answer (score 0):

To save the img in PhotoAlbum, add this in your options camera.

```
saveToPhotoAlbum: true
```

This option means you are going to get a base64/img so change it too.

```
//destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL

destinationType: 1,//Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
```

Finally save your URL

```
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
  someGreatFunctionToStoreURLInYourDB(imageData);
  //imageData is the URL to the sandbox
})
```

If you want to save the photos in your app directory use this.

> $scope.cfd = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
>   $scope.ccd = cordova.file.cacheDirectory;

```
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
        var currentName = imageData.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
        var namePath = imageData.substr(0, imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        //creacion de un objeto fileEntry apartir el URI de la camara
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL($scope.cfd, function(dirEntry){
          console.log(dirEntry);
          dirEntry.getFile(currentName, {
            create: true,
            exclusive: false
          }, function(fileEntry){
            $cordovaFile.writeFile($scope.cfd, currentName, fileEntry, true)
              .then(function(successCreate){

                console.log(successCreate.target.localURL);
                $scope.imagenes.push(currentName);

              }, function(errorCreate){
                console.log(errorCreate);
              });
          });

        });            
})
```

Comment: $scope.imagenes.push(currentName); here is where I store the current name so change it.

Comment: Hi David , thanks for the code.
any idea how can I reterive the images i saved on file system and display on the html ?

Comment: As you can read. All the images name are stored in $scope.images so you can use `<img ng-src="path/where/you/store/{{images}}">`

Comment: it works , Thanks .
any idea how can I save the image URL , beacuse when ever I close the app and open it again , the image dispear